# Release resources with audioplayers flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-audioplayers

I am using the audioplayers plugin to play a sound with 2 seconds duration.
I would like let's say spotify or youtube to continue playing once the sound is over.
Currently it stops youtube and youtube doesn't resume afterwards.

```
class AudioPlayerService {
  static const audioFilePath = 'audio/notification.wav';

  final AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();

  Future<void> play() async {
    await player.play(AssetSource(audioFilePath));
  }
}
```